How do I read the original pdf file in set indexer datasource in a custom WebApiSkill after enabling "Allow Skillset to read file data"
I see the following under my indexer settings:

When hovering over it I read the following:

True means the original file data obtained from your blob data source
is preserved. This allows passing the original file to a custom skill,
or to the Document Extraction skill.

How do I read the original pdf file in the associated blob data source in a custom WebApiSkill?
file_data_base64 = value.get('data', {}).get('file_data', '')
...

EDIT
I enabled Allow Skillset to read file data in the indexer. My full setup:

WebApiSkill inputs

inputs=[
    InputFieldMappingEntry(name="file_data", source="/document/file_data")
],


WebApiSkill input reading

import azure.functions as func
import datetime
import json
import logging
import base64
import fitz
from io import BytesIO

app = func.FunctionApp()
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


@app.route(route="CustomSplitSkill", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
def CustomSplitSkill(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    try:
        req_body = req.get_json()
        logging.info('Request body parsed successfully.')
    except ValueError:
        logging.error(f"Invalid input: {e}")
        return func.HttpResponse("Invalid input", status_code=400)

    # 'values' expected top-level key in the request body
    response_body = {"values": []}
    for value in req_body.get('values', []):
        recordId = value.get('recordId')
        file_data_base64 = value.get('data', {}).get('file_data', '').get('data', '')
        if not file_data_base64:
            logging.error("No file_data found in the request.")
            return func.HttpResponse("Invalid input: No file_data found", status_code=400)

        try:
            file_data = base64.b64decode(file_data_base64)

            try:
                pdf_document = fitz.open(stream=BytesIO(file_data), filetype='pdf')
            except fitz.FileDataError as e:
                logging.error(f"Failed to open PDF document: {e}")
                return func.HttpResponse("Failed to open PDF document", status_code=400)
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(f"An unexpected error occurred while opening the PDF document: {e}")
                return func.HttpResponse("An unexpected error occurred", status_code=500)
            
            if pdf_document.page_count == 0:
                logging.error("No pages found in the PDF document.")
                return func.HttpResponse("Invalid PDF: No pages found", status_code=400)

            extracted_text = ""
            for page_num in range(pdf_document.page_count):
                page = pdf_document.load_page(page_num)
                extracted_text += page.get_text()

            combined_list = [{'textItems': ['text1', 'text2'], 'numberItems': [0, 1]}]  # i deleted the chunking and associated page extraction for simplicity

            response_record = {
                "recordId": recordId,
                "data": {
                    "subdata": combined_list
                }
            }
            response_body['values'].append(response_record)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Error processing file_data: {e}")
            return func.HttpResponse("Error processing file_data", status_code=500)

    logging.info('Function executed successfully.')
    return func.HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_body), mimetype="application/json")

The error:
Message:
Could not execute skill because the Web Api request failed.

Details:
Web Api response status: 'NotFound', Web Api response details: ''

Given that I have projections I cannot debug this properly as debugging is not supported with projections. The logging does not seem to log the specific error either despite the error handling and checks.

only this error? see the indexer logs and details for exact reason of failure

Sorry, details added

Your web api is not giving back the response kindly check it.

It has to do with how the data is read. Which is also part of the question. I have generated and encoded a pdf which is part of my curl command to test the script. That works, the pdf is read correctly. But it does not work in the pipeline

Please add your web api skill full code.

Skill code updated

can you check the logs of the function. Because your function returning empty.

In you azure function under invocations tab you can see error count where you find the logs and details.

Thank you. This last debug tip was very helpful. The error appeared clearly there. I have been looking at the wrong place (log stream) for too long...

The input to your WebApiSkill in your skillset has to be set to:
"inputs": [
      {
        "name": "file_data",
        "source": "/document/file_data"
      }
    ]

Enable "Allow skillset to read file data" in indexer:
    indexing_parameters_configuration = IndexingParametersConfiguration(
        allow_skillset_to_read_file_data=True
    )

    # otherwise: HTTP response error: () Configuration property 'queryTimeout' is not supported for the data source of type 'azureblob'.
    indexing_parameters_configuration.query_timeout = None

    indexer = SearchIndexer(  
        name=indexer_name,  
        description="Chunks, pages and embeddings",  
        skillset_name=skillset_name,  
        target_index_name=target_index_name,  
        data_source_name=data_source_name,
        parameters={"configuration": indexing_parameters_configuration} 
    ) 

The file_data input is base64 encoded, so first it has to be decoded, and then opened as a byte-stream with the PDF reader of your choice:
import re
import azure.functions as func
import datetime
import json
import logging
import base64
import fitz
from io import BytesIO

app = func.FunctionApp()
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


@app.route(route="CustomSplitSkill", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
def CustomSplitSkill(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    try:
        req_body = req.get_json()
        logging.info('Request body parsed successfully.')
    except ValueError:
        logging.error(f"Invalid input: {e}")
        return func.HttpResponse("Invalid input", status_code=400)

    # 'values' expected top-level key in the request body
    response_body = {"values": []}
    for value in req_body.get('values', []):
        recordId = value.get('recordId')
        file_data_base64 = value.get('data', {}).get('file_data', '').get('data', '')
        if not file_data_base64:
            logging.error("No file_data found in the request.")
            return func.HttpResponse("Invalid input: No file_data found", status_code=400)

        try:
            file_data = base64.b64decode(file_data_base64)

            try:
                pdf_document = fitz.open(stream=BytesIO(file_data), filetype='pdf')
            except fitz.FileDataError as e:
                logging.error(f"Failed to open PDF document: {e}")
                return func.HttpResponse("Failed to open PDF document", status_code=400)
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(f"An unexpected error occurred while opening the PDF document: {e}")
                return func.HttpResponse("An unexpected error occurred", status_code=500)
            
            if pdf_document.page_count == 0:
                logging.error("No pages found in the PDF document.")
                return func.HttpResponse("Invalid PDF: No pages found", status_code=400)

            combined_list = [{'textItems': ['text1', 'text2'], 'numberItems': [0, 1]}]  # I deleted the chunking and associated page extraction in order to reduce the amount of code

            response_record = {
                "recordId": recordId,
                "data": {
                    "subdata": combined_list
                }
            }
            response_body['values'].append(response_record)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Error processing file_data: {e}")
            return func.HttpResponse("Error processing file_data", status_code=500)

    logging.info('Function executed successfully.')
    return func.HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_body), mimetype="application/json")


According to this documentation when you enable the allowSkillsetToReadFileData parameter in the indexer,
you will get the file data in the path /document/file_data in document context.
The same is passed to your custom web api skillset inputs.
"inputs": [
      {
        "name": "file_data",
        "source": "/document/file_data"
      }
    ]

and it is accessed in the function like below.
file_data = value.get('data', {}).get('file_data', '')


Thank you for your response. Looks promising!

I just tried it out but something is failing...

Glad you find out the error and fixed the code.

Thank you for the support. Feels weird that there is not examples for page extraction online. To me it was a no-brainer to use a pdf python reader to achieve this but I have no idea what others are doing xD
